# On premise Azure DevOps diff coverage requirements

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, code-coverage, pull-request, azure-devops-server

I'm using and on-premise installation of Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2. I'm trying to configure the build pipeline to obtain the diff coverage indicators in the files tab of pull requests as shown in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops
I created two .Net Core projects one in Azure Devops Cloud and one in our on-premise server. The indicators appear in the cloud project but not on the on-premise hosted one. The only difference between both is that the on-premise linux build agent is based on RedHat instead of Ubuntu.

Are there requirements on the server or software that need to be installed on the server or the agent to get this coverage indicators working?

These are the relevant steps of my yaml pipeline:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore task'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/NuGet.config'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test $(buildConfiguration) v2'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*Test/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)  --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" --collect:"Code Coverage" -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=json,cobertura,lcov,teamcity,opencover,coverlet -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.SplitCoverage="True"'
    publishTestResults: true
```

Comment: Hi, have you by any chance checked my answer? Does it help resolve your concern?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently not available for Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2.

[image: TFS 2020 TEST RESULTS]

Currently, we can only see the feature in the [RTW Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2020?view=azure-devops#azure-devops-server-2020-rc1-release-date-june-30-2020) for Azure DevOps Server 2020 RC1.

[image: Azure DevOps Server 2020 RC1]

For this, you may access this URL: https://aka.ms/AzDevOpsIdeas to submit any comments and proposals for future releases and implementations.

Comment: 2020 RTW was released in October 2020 and according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2020?view=azure-devops-2020#repos it should show the indicators. 2020.1.2 is a release from May 2022, so it should contain the same feature. But neither do display the diff coverage indicators. Maybe there is a mistake in the Microsoft documentation.